# how to create your own rails generator without needing an argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

It seems that I am stuck figuring out so that my generator doesn't need an argument. So for instance my generator code is this:

```rb
class MyGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def generate_stylesheet
     copy_file "my.css", "public/stylesheets/my.css"    
  end
end
```

But when I do `rails g my` rails always asks for an extra argument. Can you show me how so it doesn't need an extra argument?

Thanks.

Comment: i dont think that is posible. You have to tell rails which generator they have to use. To run your generator you need to do `rails g my` that run MyGenerator (class) for more details check => http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: hmm, you read my question wrong. I understand you need to specify the generator name - my issue lies with passing an argument to the specific generator. so I can do this - "rails g my" and not "rails g my <some argument>"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `class MyGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base` instead of `class MyGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase`

Comment: Hmm... I knew i tried that too...  but oh well, im good now. thanks.

Comment: Hello from 2022! Wow, 11 years later. Just wanna say for those who come here in the future, as of today, this answer worked for me!